# Comparar valores em group by sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Aconteceu algo muito inusitado em meu banco. Alguns registros foram inputados mais de uma vez (7 a 13) para ser mais exato. Isso ocorreu por erro de software que já foi resolvido.

Agora necessito excluir os registros duplicados, porém tenho o seguinte cenário:

- Os registros que não foram movimentados, posso deixar apenas o menor
  Id;
- Os registros que todas as cópias foram movimentadas *juntas*
  deixo apenas o menor Id;
- porém por alguma gracinha do destino, possuo o terceiro caso. Algumas
  duplicatas se movimentaram sozinhas, ou seja, das 7 copias apenas uma
  ficou correta e as outras não a acompanharam.

Chegando ao cerne da questão, é possível fazer um "if" dentro de um select?
Fiz esta consulta que me retorna o seguinte:

```
SELECT    IdLoteProduto ,
          Serie ,
          Saiu ,
          COUNT(Id) AS cont ,
          MIN(Id) AS old
FROM      dbo.SerieProduto
WHERE     empresa = 385
      AND IdLoteProduto = 264
GROUP BY  IdLoteProduto ,
          Serie ,
          Saiu
```

Esta consulta me retorna as seguintes informações:

```
Id  Serie               Saiu Rep  Id mais antigo
264 8955031700194659020 0    6    2217691
264 8955031700194659020 1    1    2217721
```

Isto em uma consulta que me retorna todos os valores.

Gostaria de saber se há forma de neste caso selecionar o Id da segunda opção, porém, nos casos abaixo ele me devolver os números corretos.

```
Id  Serie               Saiu Rep  Id mais antigo
264 8955031700194659020 0    7    1234567
264 8955031700194659021 1    7    1234897
```

Neste caso são seriais diferentes ou seja, deve me devolver o Id do primeiro e do segundo.

Espero ter sido claro.

Por favor, se puder melhorar minha pergunta, me diga como, que farei.

Comment: Não sei se entendi: você precisa fazer um `MIN(id)` quando em um caso, e `MAX(id)` quando noutro? Qual o critério para saber quando deve fazer o `MAX(id)`? A princípio eu sugeriria o uso de `CASE`, mas dependendo da complexidade do critério talvez seja necessário o uso de "função de janelamento", como `OVER()`...

Comment: Problema recorrente , uma busca no Google garanto trará soluções quase pronta "remover registros duplicados sql server"

Comment: Como você sabe qual o registro que ficou correto?

Comment: @Motta acho que você não entendeu, os registros duplicados não são o problema, o problema é que alguns registros duplicados não foram movimentados juntos, apenas um foi e suas cópias não, logo, este que foi deve ser mantido e suas cópias deletadas

Comment: @Sorack É uma regra um tanto quanto simples, digamos que eu tenha um registro com 7 cópias iguais, o que deve permanecer é a mais antiga, ou seja, a de menor Id, porém se este registro estiver diferente de suas cópias, o diferente deve se manter.

Comment: @nunks.lol Quase isso, não seria um MAX e sim o Id do registro que está diferente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrupe os resultados contando-os. Depois disso pegue o mínimo com o menor número de repetições.

```
WITH repeticoes AS (
  SELECT sp.empresa,
         sp.idloteproduto,
         sp.serie,
         sp.saiu,
         sp.id,
         COUNT(sp.id) AS quantidade
  FROM dbo.SerieProduto sp
  WHERE sp.empresa = 385
    AND sp.idloteproduto = 264
  GROUP BY sp.empresa,
           sp.idloteproduto,
           sp.serie,
           sp.saiu,
           sp.id
)
SELECT r.empresa,
       r.idloteproduto,
       r.serie,
       r.saiu,
       MIN(r.id) AS old
  FROM repeticoes r
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                    FROM repeticoes r2
                   WHERE r2.empresa = r.empresa
                     AND r2.idloteproduto = r.idloteproduto
                     AND r2.serie = r.serie
                     AND r2.saiu = r.saiu
                     AND r2.quantidade < r.quantidade)
 GROUP BY r.empresa,
          r.idloteproduto,
          r.serie,
          r.saiu,
          r.quantidade
```

Veja funcionando no [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/55ed6/2).

Comment: O código está errado. Sugiro que teste antes de postar.

Comment: @JoséDiz sugiro que você me disponibilize a base para teste então. Não vi uma resposta sua, o que indica que ficou com preguiça de tentar resolver. Se não tem essa capacidade não haja como crítico. Ao que parece suas atitudes são para atrapalhar e não para ajudar, o que não faz sentido em um fórum de auxílio. Procure outro hobbie.

Comment: @JoséDiz pronto, adicionado `Fiddle` com a comprovação da resposta. Aguardo a remoção do `downvote`. Se quiser pode usar o banco que eu criei, já que até agora aparentemente você não teve "tempo" de criar um para responder.